# How to make a learning curve

Tags: r, ggplot2

getting error while making a learning curve on binary data

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyverse)
 library(tidytext)
 library(ggplot2)
```

#data frame

structure(list(ID = c(32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L,
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L,
34L, 34L, 34L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 43L, 43L,
43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L,
47L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L,
56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 59L,
59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L,
69L, 69L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 72L,
72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 79L,
80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L,
81L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 83L, 83L,
83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L,
84L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L,
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L,
123L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 125L, 125L,
125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 126L,
126L, 126L, 126L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L,
128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 137L, 137L, 137L,
137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 138L,
138L, 138L, 139L, 139L, 139L, 139L, 139L, 139L, 139L, 139L, 140L,
140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 147L, 147L, 147L, 147L,
147L, 147L, 147L, 147L, 148L, 148L, 148L, 148L, 148L, 148L, 148L,
148L, 149L, 149L, 149L, 149L, 149L, 149L, 149L, 149L, 150L, 150L,
150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L,
151L, 151L, 151L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L,
159L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 160L, 160L, 160L,
160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L), Measurement = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), Value = c(4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L,
1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L,
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 9L, 14L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 6L,
0L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L,
0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L,
0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 3L,
5L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 18L, 14L, 15L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 2L,
11L, 9L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L,
3L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 5L,
2L, 7L, 9L, 13L, 14L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 1L,
5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L,
5L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 20L, 8L, 10L, 4L,
3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
10L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 6L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Success = c(1, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA,
-312L), class = "data.frame")
then

```
#Read the the file

individual_df <- read.csv("C:/Users/ASUS/OneDrive/Desktop/Working_R_Sheets/output_list -           Second_copy2.csv")
```

Then i plotted the data

```
ggplot(individual_df, aes(x = as.factor(Measurement), y = Value, group = ID, color = factor(ID))) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 5, fill = "white") +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  labs(x = "Measurement", y = "Value", color = "ID") +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "ID")
```

then i got this nice plot

[image]

Then

```
# Add a new column "success" where 3 or above 3 from the value counts will considered as success

individual_df$Success <- ifelse(individual_df$Value >= 3, 1, 0)

# Fit logistic regression model

model <- glm(Success ~ Measurement, data = individual_df, family = binomial)
 summary(model)

# Create a new data frame for prediction

prediction_data <- data.frame(
  Measurement = seq(min(individual_df$Measurement), max(individual_df$Measurement), length.out = 100)
)

# Predict probabilities

prediction_data$fit <- predict(model, newdata = prediction_data, type = "response")

# Create the plot

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = prediction_data, aes(x = Measurement, y = fit, fill = as.factor(ID)), shape = 21,           size = 4) +
  geom_line(data = prediction_data, aes(x = Measurement, y = fit), color = "blue", size = 1) +
  labs(x = "Measurement", y = "Success", title = "Logistic Regression") +
  theme_minimal()
```

I am getting error here

```
Error in `geom_point()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error:
! object 'ID' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred
```

i want a plot like this

[image]

So here is the data_frame that i imported to R

[text](https://github.com/conda-suman07/Learn_Python/blob/7aae4cbb522dacb854bb0b0adc2779eb62c3d1e9/output_list%20-%20Second_copy2.csv)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include a sample of your data using `dput()` instead of external links?

Comment: I am new here, where to use the dput() ?

Comment: Run `dput(individual_df)` in R, and then edit your question and paste the contents in a code block.

Comment: It's not clear what you are wanting the final plot to show. Is it _just_ the prediction of failure vs success as a probability?

Comment: @AllanCameron hi. Thank you for your text. So on the X-axis will be the measurements/ events from 1-8 and on the y axis will be probability data and fill with the IDs . So the plot will be the learning curve or IDs wheather they learn over the time or not.

Comment: @Conda_suman07 but your model doesn't _have_ IDs. There is no ID column in your prediction data, because there is no ID in the model itself. Your model shows what happens to all of the IDs _on average_, so there is only one prediction line. If you want to show the raw data for each ID, your plot already does that, but you can't get a different prediction for each ID if ID does not appear in your model. Are you maybe looking for a mixed effects model with ID as a random variable?

Comment: @AllanCameron Hi thank you so much. Exactly that's my point, I want my ID in my model. But I want ID as a factor. But I tried to do it with "model <- glm(Success ~ Measurement*as.factor(ID), data = individual_df, family = binomial), it didn't work actually. You are right, it is just taking the first ID in the prediction. I want a mixed-effect model, you are right. Any idea how to do that? I want the plot like the pic i uploaded.

Comment: See my answer below for running a mixed model logistic regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model you are using does not take ID into account, but instead assumes that the log odds of success varies linearly according to Measurement. If you want predictions for each ID, you will need to include ID in your model, presumably as a random effect.

The following code downloads your data directly from source, carries out a mixed-effects logistic regression, then plots predictions across the range for each ID:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

df <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/conda-suman07/' %>%
  paste0('Learn_Python/7aae4cbb522dacb854bb0b0adc2779eb62c3d1e9') %>%
  paste0('/output_list%20-%20Second_copy2.csv') %>%
  read.csv() %>%
  mutate(ID = factor(ID)) %>%
  mutate(Success = ifelse(individual_df$Value >= 3, 1, 0))

mod <- glmer(Success ~ Measurement|ID, family = binomial, data = df)

expand.grid(ID = unique(df$ID), Measurement = 0:7) %>%
  mutate(Probability = predict(mod, ., type = 'response')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Measurement, y = Probability, color = ID, group = ID)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = 'white', size = 2.5)
```

[image]

It is important that you check the assumptions of your model here, and what it actually means. This model states that the log odds of success is linearly related to Measurement, but that the effect can be positive or negative, depending on the individual. I'm not sure your raw data supports the use of such a model. To me, it looks as though there is a large drop in values between Measurement 0 and 1, then a gradual increase as Measurement increases above 1. Getting a model to represent your data is very context specific, and might need the input of a statistician if you are unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Hi, you are absolutely correct. So the measurements are the events, So basically there are events per ID or individual but some individuals didn't perform certain tasks in all the events. So the main question for me is that do individuals learn a certain task over time or not. So here in my case, the learning curve I expect to increase over time here in my case measurements or events.